# How to open camera on client side with OpenCV, Face Recognition, Flask, Python 3 and Heroku

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I'm trying to make web app using OpenCV, Flask, Face Recognition hosted on Heroku. On localhost, everything is working how it suppose to but on Heroku, I can't open client camera. I know I need javascript or WebSocket to achieve this.
All that I could found with javascript is how to stream from the camera on the browser which is not good for me because I need to open the OpenCV frame for the face detection and recognition. Also, I was looking for WebSocket and flask-socket but they only send messages, not video.

Here is my code:
app.py

```
'''Face Detection Login App '''

import random, string
import face_recognition
import cv2
import glob
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/article')
def article():
    return render_template('article.html')


@app.route('/registered')
def registered():
    return render_template('registered.html')


@app.route('/reject')
def reject():
    return render_template('reject.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():

    page_name = 'reject'

    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# Load faces
    faces = 'faces/*.jpg*'
    face = glob.glob(faces)
    for fn in face:
        try_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(f'{fn}')
        print(f'{fn}')
        try_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(try_image)

    if not try_face_encoding:
        print("No face found on the image")
        return redirect(url_for(page_name))

    try_face_encoding = try_face_encoding[0]

# Array of faces
    known_face_encodings = [
        try_face_encoding,
    ]

    face_locations = []
    face_encodings = []
    process_this_frame = True

    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

# Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

    rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

    if process_this_frame:
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(
        rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(
                known_face_encodings, face_encoding)

            if True in matches:
                first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                page_name = 'article'
                break

# if user is NOT found release the capture and redirect
    video_capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return redirect(url_for(page_name))


# Register
@app.route('/register', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    faceCascade = 
    cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

while(True):
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        if w <= 200:
            x = 0
            y = 20
            text_color = (0, 255, 0)
            cv2.putText(
                frame, "Please get closer", (x, y),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, text_color, thickness=1
            )
        else:
            x = 0
            y = 20
            text_color = (0, 255, 0)
            cv2.putText(
                frame, "Press q to take image", (x, y),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, text_color, thickness=1
            )

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        image_name = str(random.randint(1, 100))
        cv2.imwrite(f'faces/{image_name}.jpg', frame)
        # cv2.imwrite('faces/try.jpg', frame)
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

return redirect(url_for('registered'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'secret123'
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
    app.run()
```

and my HTML is simple. Pages that say to register or login with two buttons who calls functions login and register

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you can look into the above github link as i used the same to create a sample poc for myself.

[Face match in python using Facenet and their pretrained model]


  : https://github.com/arunmandal53/facematch

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how this can help me to access client camera using OpenCV and Heroku. This will work on localhost.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This cannot work the way you're building it.
OpenCV will try to open the camera on the same machine as the server is currently running. On localhost, that's your own laptop. On heroku, that's a server somewhere in an AWS datacenter (and it doesn't have a webcam).

You need to capture the video in javascript/html, stream the data to your server and then analyze it server-side.
See this tutorial for how you can access the webcam within the browser: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm

Comment: Thank you a lot for an answer. That's OK for registering user since I can open camera and save image. But when user want to login I need to open camera and run python function for face recognition to compare image from webcam and image that's saved. Do toy think I need to rewrite everything so that would be possible?

Comment: Yes. You can't access the camera server-side.

Comment: Thank you. Well, I guess there is nothing else I can do than to start all over. Thank you again