# Access to the camera from the system the application is running on

Tags: javascript, python, django, opencv

I am building a web application with django and opencv for computer vision. In the web application there exists a button which when pressed starts the web cam of my computer. The problem is when i host the web application using my IP and access the application with a different computer and press the button, The webcam in my computer start.

I knew the problem lied in this line of code

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

I looked online and found this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661209/how-to-open-camera-on-client-side-with-opencv-face-recognition-flask-python-3) , which asks me to use javascript to access the webcam.

1. Is that the best option available or can I somehow change that line of opencv code to access the camera in the system the application is running on?
2. If there is no better way to do it than javascript, then I would also like to know once I access the webcam and display the feed onto the screen, how do I link the rest of the python code like the face detectors and classifiers to the javascript code?

I have just started getting my hands dirty with python and i still have a lot to learn.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does your question differ from the one you have linked?

Comment: I want to know if I can accomplish the task with python itself. I also want to know how to link the python code with the video feed from javascript

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different ways to accomplish what you're trying to do so you will need to focus on *how* you want to design your application.

If you only need to perform face-detection and tracking on the client camera you might want to take a look to https://trackingjs.com/ , a JS library that is able to perform various simple computer vision tasks on the client-side.

If you need to perform some more sophisticated image processing or classification tasks on the incoming video stream you might want to do something like:

**STEP 1:** Get the client camera feed using JS on the client-side.

**STEP 2:** Serve your web application in HTTPS mode (you will need to generate an SSL certificate): if you don't do that, the JS `getUserMedia()` function won't execute and you will get the

> getusermedia no longer works on insecure origins

If you're uncertain how to generate an SSL certificate in Python,  https://pypi.org/project/pyOpenSSL/ is the way to go.

**STEP 3:** Now that the client camera is opened, use WebSocket to stream your client video feed to your back-end server

**STEP 4:** You're now on the server side and you can perform all the funcy processing here and stream back to the client through WebSocket the result of your computation.

**STEP 5:** The JS WebSocket listener on the client side will receive all incoming information and will display the final result on client screen.

Hope this helps